# How to secure Jetty to only allow access from loopback(localhost)

Tags: security, jetty, localhost

**How can I secure [jetty](http://www.mortbay.org/jetty/) to only allow connections from localhost?** This means a connection to *server A on System A* from *Client B on System B* has to fail. I know I can do this by configuring my firewall (so please no answers about this). I just want Jetty to only listen on localhost(loopback).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have not tried this but the usual method is to bind server to localhost (i.e. to IP 127.0.0.1). That means that Jetty server will listen to only connections that have *localhost* as their destination address.

A quick googling revealed this http://old.nabble.com/How-to-make-Jetty-bind-to-specific-IP-address---to11667378.html#a11669524 :

> add this entry to SelectChannelConnector for example:
>
> `<Set name="Host">127.0.0.1</Set>`

Comment: Yup after a little bit more searching I also found something like this. Now We should provide good documentation on stackoverflow. I am writting something myself right now.

Comment: If you are using the standard Jetty package in Debian/Ubuntu/etc, the way to do this is to edit /etc/default/jetty and set JETTY_HOST to 127.0.0.1 there.

Answer (score 24):

I found the answer to my question myself after a little bit more [googling](http://www.paralint.com/blog/2007/05/18/making-jetty-listen-to-the-local-interface-only/).

The answer is (Tested on jetty-distribution-7.0.1.v20091125):

1. Locate jetty.xml (etc/jetty.xml)
2. Search for `<Call name="addConnector">`
3. Set `<Set name="Host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host" default="127.0.0.1"/></Set>` before line `<Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port"/></Set>`
4. That's it. Restart jetty server (`java -jar start.jar`). The server should output something like:

> 2009-12-23 23:02:09.291:INFO::Started
>   SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8080

The import thing is that it should say 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0 means listen on all ips on the machine.

> P.S: I wanted to secure [apache solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) (which is
>   using jetty) which can be achieved in
>   the same way.

You can also bind to localhost programmatically(embed jetty) by:

```
Server server = new Server();
Connector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
connector.setHost("localhost");
connector.setPort(80);
server.addConnector(connector);
```

Comment: What to do if `<Call name="addConnector">` is not found. Could a more fuller example have been given?

Answer (score 15):

For Jetty 9 embedded, this code works.

```
    Server server = new Server();                                       
    ServerConnector connector=new ServerConnector(server);
    connector.setPort(80);
    connector.setHost("localhost");        
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{connector});
```

Comment: Even easier is to use `new Server(InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("127.0.0.1", port))`

Answer (score 10):

You can set the `jetty.host` property during start of the virtual machine:

```
java -Djetty.host=127.0.0.1 -jar start.jar
```

Btw same for `jetty.port`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this using .htaccess but for some reason the localhost filtering does not work. If you want to allow traffic from a particular external IP and block all others try
<strike>http://technologyenablingbusiness.blogspot.com/2011/03/setting-security-in-solr-running-on.html</strike>

**EDIT:** Archived version of page at https://web.archive.org/web/20110429184536/http://technologyenablingbusiness.blogspot.com/2011/03/setting-security-in-solr-running-on.html

Comment: The referenced link no longer exists - I was unable to find an alternative source for this information, but maybe the answer can be edited to include one if anyone is able to.

Comment: The link no longer works, there is a wayback machine [cache](https://web.archive.org/web/20110429184536/http://technologyenablingbusiness.blogspot.com/2011/03/setting-security-in-solr-running-on.html) of it.

Answer (score 1):

As of Jetty 7.1.5 (released in July 2010), you may initialize the Jetty server like this:

```
Server server = new Server(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8080));
```

Remember to `import java.net.InetSocketAddress;`.

Reference: [org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/jetty-11/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html)'s constructor.